# 2 relations between 2 tables - One-to-many & one-to-one (nullable) EF Code First

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, foreign-keys, relationship

I know there are lot of questions regarding this problem, but after a few days thinking about it I still can't figure out how to make it work.

I am writing an app for automatic calibrations of devices.

I have 2 Tables `Transmitter` and `Calibration`.

A `Transmitter` can have zero,one or many `Calibration`, a `Calibration` has to belong to a transmitter.

Now a `Transmitter` should have an `OfficialCalibration`, which can be null, for example for the time there are no calibrations done.

So I wanted to implement this without a joiner Table, by just having an OfficialCalibrationId in `Transmitter`. (Both ways I will need to update 2 tables, but so I have less overall tables).
 Also woud be good to have this relation as navigationProperty so I can call `Transmitter.OfficialCalibration` and get the right `Calibration`.

So it's possible to do this without a "Join"-Table in EF Code First?

I tried the approach using one-To-Many relations and an added constraint to define a one-to-one, but this way I have 2 problems

1. I need a navigation Property `Tranmitters` in Calibration, which I don't want
2. It doesn't work, since when I "register" a transmitter the ActualCalibrationId is Null, because there are no Calibration for this transmitter.

Now I tried so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(of Transmitter)
    .HasMany(Function(c)c.Calibrations)
    .WithRequired(Function(t)t.Transmitter)
    .HasForeignKey(Function(t)t.TransmitterId)
```

But still have problems with the one to one relation showed in the image below.

The relation is `Transmitter.Id` -> `Calibration.Id` but should be `Transmitter.OfficialCalibrationId` -> `Calibration.Id`

This way I can't force a Calibration be an `OfficialCalibration` of ONLY ONE `Transmitter` right? Can I force this some way? I can only think using a Join-Table `Transmitter_DefaultCalbration` with columns `TransmitterId` and `CalibrationId` and making `TransmitterId` a Primary Key?

[image]

I am still learning to use EF for complex scenaries so any Info or guidance would be good.

Comment: In a 1:0..1 association the entity at the 1 side (here: Transmitter) is the *principal* and the other side is the *dependent* entity. The principal entity generates (or receives) its primary key which is then copied to the dependent entity's primary key. Hence the Id => Id relationship. If you want `OfficialCalibrationId` to be the FK to the one OfficialCalibration you can only model it as a second 1 (Calibration):N (Transmitters) association and enforce it as 1:1 in code.

Comment: @GertArnold I ended up doing what you say and adding an filtered (non null value) unique index for the ActualCalibrationID. I think that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transmitter - Calibration relationship is 1-n relationship so you don't need a Junction table.

As you partially noted, you can specify the OfficialCalibration in 2 ways, inserting a property on the Transmitter (Transmitter.OfficialCalibration) or inserting a flag in the Calibration (Calibration.Default). Both relationships needs to be enforced with code because:
- if you insert the property you can't be sure that the OfficialCalibration is one of the Calibrations related to Transmitter;
- if you insert the flag you can't be sure that there is only one official calibration. Thinking when writing, probably this can be enforced with an unique index.

Some other answer:
- in general you don't need navigation properties to define relationships (you need just one of the 2 navigation properties);

If you don't want the Calibrations property this is the model in C#

```
class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Transmitter> Transmitters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Calibration> Calibrations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Calibration>()
            .HasRequired(_ => _.Transmitter);
    }

}

class Calibration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Transmitter Transmitter { get; set; }
}

class Transmitter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Calibration OfficialCalibration { get; set; }
}
```

If you prefere the default property I would implement this model (in this case I prefere to have the Calibrations navigation property)

```
class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Transmitter> Transmitters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Calibration> Calibrations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Transmitter>()
            .HasMany(_ => _.Calibrations)
            .WithRequired(_ => _.Transmitter);
    }
}

class Calibration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool? Default { get; set; }

    public virtual Transmitter Transmitter { get; set; }
}

class Transmitter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Calibration> Calibrations { get; set; }


    public Calibration GetOfficialCalibration()
    {
        // This could trigger lazy load
        return Calibrations.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Default == true);
    }

}
```